# Sorting DataArray

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following code (made it simple):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

dataList.add(4,44,444);
dataList.add(5,55,555);
dataList.add(6,66,666);
dataArrays.add(dataList);
dataList=null;

dataList.add(1,11,111);
dataList.add(2,22,222);
dataList.add(3,33,333);
dataArrays.add(dataList);
dataList=null; 
.
.
.
```

I want to sort the dataArrays by the value of the first value in the array.
I want the first array in dataArrays to be 1,11,111, then 2,22,222 etc.
What is the best practice to do so? If using Comparable - please supply the code (never used it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` i used `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` to simplify the code.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

dataList.add(4);
dataList.add(44);
dataList.add(444);
dataArrays.add(dataList);

dataList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
dataList.add(1);
dataList.add(11);
dataList.add(111);
dataArrays.add(dataList);

Collections.sort(dataArrays, new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
    public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> arg0, ArrayList<Integer> arg1) {
        return arg0.get(0).compareTo(arg1.get(0));
    }
});

System.out.println(dataArrays);
```